# How can I duplicate a category blog on the home page but still use the original article URLs?

Tags: url, category-blog

I have a category blog for News. If I click its menu item I'm taken to `/news`, and if I then click an article link I'm taken to `/news/article-title` as expected.

However, I also want to show some of that category's articles on the home page, so I've set the home page menu item type to Category Blog, with the category set to News. Now all articles are loaded with home page modules showing, and the URLs are like `/article-title`.

How can I have the category blog in both locations but force the original article URLs (and not have home page modules show)?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different methods, but the simplest (and the one that I do) would be to have the category blog at /news and use a category module and load it in an article on the home page.

Comment: What's a category module?

Comment: If you create a new module under Extensions > Modules it's called "Articles - Category". The display can be configured to be very similar to a category blog.

Comment: Thanks, but I had already tried that. The formatting is list-style and images are stripped. It's not quite the same as a blog page.